# SlickGird header row multi filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm trying to implement filters on SlickGrid so that user can enter min and max values for a given filed as shown in the image below. It works fine with single filter but i'm unable to accomplish with multi-filtering. I really appreciate if someone can guide on how to implement this or point me to an example.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied to a similar question and in my solution I made some conditional filters, and so if a condition is supplied using any of these character (>, >=, <, <=, !=, <>) I deal with it through the filter. 
See my previous answer to that similar question here: [Slickgrid-column-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752218/slickgrid-column-type/16779331)

Please note that in order to do the filtering you are asking in your, you would have to duplicate the "Price" column so that you can put in first "Price" condition (> 100) in first column and (< 200) in the second column...

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks, thats was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

provide your code sample so it will help understand and fix your issue....

However here is the example code

```
function myFilter(item, args) {     

    if((item["price"] < args.searchStringMax) && (item["price"] > args.searchStringMin)){
        return true;
    } else {            
        return false;
    }
}
```