# Pattern matching filtering in slickGrid

Tags: javascript, filtering, slickgrid

I like the functionality of the Filter in this example:
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

where filtering is done by matching pattern i.e if i enter 2 in search box , I will get
2 , 21, 22 , 222  ....2*

But my grid-layout is like the one given in this example

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

where if I enter 2 in search box , I will get only rows containing 2 and not 2 , 21, 22 , 222  ....2*

Is it possible to have the Filters functionality from the first link, with the layout of grid  from the second link? Thanks!

Comment: Ask your question clearly

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned, your question is really unclear!!! Though I'm not sure if you are looking for conditional filters (>, >=, etc..) is that what you are intending to do? If that is what you are looking for then I would suggest you read my answers from these previous post here: [SlickGird header row multi filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057825/slickgird-header-row-multi-filter/17075215#17075215) and here 
[SlickGrid column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752218/slickgrid-column-type/16779331)